# Why does using an 'if' statement give me better performance?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, x86, atomic

When compiling the following program in VC++2015 under Release mode, with optimizations set to Ox (Full Optimization), I somehow get better performance even though there is an additional conditional check.

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a33b42a28548d3e4 (which doesn't demonstrate the performance difference, because g++ generates near-identical code for the two versions).

Running this program gives me a lower execution time for **2.**. This goes against common sense for me, since **2.** has an `if` statement to check every time.

I get an average of 105ms for **1.** and an average of 86ms for **2.** on my machine. The demo also shows a difference, but only a 5ms difference that still favors **2.**; what is causing this?

---

Here is the full code that is actually giving me the big difference in execution time. Note that it doesn't actually use two functions. I just comment out the pertinent section in `operator++()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <atomic>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T = std::size_t>
class atomic_counter
{
public:
    using size_type = T;

    atomic_counter() : count_{ 0 }
    {
        assert( count_.is_lock_free() );
    }

    atomic_counter& operator++()
    {
        ++count_;                             // 1.
        //auto prev_count = ++count_;         // 2.
        //if ( prev_count == std::numeric_limits<size_type>::min() )
        //  throw std::overflow_error( "atomic_counter::operator++(): counter overflow" );

        return *this;
    }
    atomic_counter& operator--()
    {
        auto prev_count = --count_;
        if ( prev_count == std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max() )
            throw std::underflow_error( "atomic_counter::operator--() : counter underflow" );

        return *this;
    }

    size_type count() const
    {
        return count_.load();
    }

public:
    std::atomic<size_type> count_;
};

template
<
    typename Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock,
    typename Unit = std::chrono::milliseconds,
    typename F,
    typename... FArgs
>
long long measure_execution_time( F&& f, FArgs&&... fargs )
{
    auto time_begin = Clock::now();
    f( std::forward<FArgs>( fargs )... );
    auto time_end = Clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<Unit>( time_end - time_begin ).count();
}

int main()
{
    auto hardware_concurrency = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::size_t constexpr loop_count = 15'000'000;
    atomic_counter<> ac;

    auto lambda = [&] ( auto&& n )
    {
        for ( atomic_counter<>::size_type i{ 0 }; i < n; ++i )
            ++ac;
    };

    long long avg = 0;
    for ( std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < 20; ++i )
    {
        auto time = measure_execution_time<>( lambda, loop_count );
        std::cout << i + 1 << ".\t" << time << " ms\n";
        avg += time;
    }

    std::cout << "Avg:\t" << avg / 20 << " ms\n";
}
```

Consistent results for **1.**:

[image: Test 1]

Consistent results for **2.**:

[image: Test 2]

Assembly generated for **1.**:

```
000000013FA110F0  lea         rcx,[rsp+38h]  
000000013FA110F5  call        std::chrono::steady_clock::now (013FA11000h)+100000000h  
000000013FA110FA  mov         eax,2160EC0h  
000000013FA110FF  nop  
000000013FA11100 loopv1: mov    ecx,1  
000000013FA11105  lock xadd   qword ptr [ac],rcx  
000000013FA1110C  sub         rax,1  
000000013FA11110  jne    loopv1 ;   main+70h (013FA11100h)  
000000013FA11112  lea         rcx,[rsp+40h]  
000000013FA11117  call        std::chrono::steady_clock::now (013FA11000h)+100000000h
```

Assembly generated for **2.**:

```
long long measure_execution_time( F&& f, FArgs&&... fargs )
{
000000013F871230  mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx  
000000013F871235  push        rdi  
000000013F871236  sub         rsp,50h  
000000013F87123A  mov         rdi,rcx  
000000013F87123D  mov         rbx,rdx  
    auto time_begin = Clock::now();
000000013F871240  lea         rcx,[rsp+70h]  
000000013F871245  call        std::chrono::steady_clock::now (013F871110h)  
    f( std::forward<FArgs>( fargs )... );
000000013F87124A  xor         r9d,r9d  
000000013F87124D  cmp         qword ptr [rbx],r9  
000000013F871250  jbe         measure_execution_time<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::ratio<1,1000> >,<lambda_fb2a7610a6d36531125f2c739fce673b> & __ptr64,unsigned __int64 const & __ptr64>+41h (013F871271h)  
000000013F871252 loopv2: mov    rax,qword ptr [rdi]   ; top of the inner loop
000000013F871255  mov         r8d,1  
000000013F87125B  lock xadd   qword ptr [rax],r8  
000000013F871260  lea         rax,[r8+1]  
000000013F871264  test        rax,rax  
000000013F871267  je          measure_execution_time<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::ratio<1,1000> >,<lambda_fb2a7610a6d36531125f2c739fce673b> & __ptr64,unsigned __int64 const & __ptr64>+7Bh (013F8712ABh)  
000000013F871269  inc         r9  
000000013F87126C  cmp         r9,qword ptr [rbx]   ; loop upper-bound in memory
000000013F87126F  jb  loopv2  ;         measure_execution_time<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::ratio<1,1000> >,<lambda_fb2a7610a6d36531125f2c739fce673b> & __ptr64,unsigned __int64 const & __ptr64>+22h (013F871252h)  
    auto time_end = Clock::now();
000000013F871271  lea         rcx,[time_end]  
000000013F871276  call        std::chrono::steady_clock::now (013F871110h)
```

Comment: This could be some aggressive UB optimization, although I  don't see the UB, unless you instantiate with a signed type.

Comment: What does the assembly say?

Comment: High resolution timings are a black art.  I note that your method 2. is called after method 1.  The advantage may well be due to instruction caches being in a better position when the second method runs giving it the advantage.  Do you see the same advantage if method 2 is run first then followed by method 1?

Comment: @P.Hinker I've added the exact code that gives me the timings I talked about. I didn't want to include it at first because I wanted to keep the post short.

Comment: Also note, that test is probably 'free', since branch prediction is going to get it right every time.

Comment: @sp2danny I've added a more detailed section that gives me the actual big difference in results. Even if branch prediction is playing into it, shouldn't I get the same timing, or at least a much lesser difference? In debug mode, #2 is actually a lot slower.

Comment: What CPU? (e.g. AMD Piledriver, Intel Haswell?  Or just say Intel i5-2500k or whatever, and we can look up what core microarchitecture that model has.)  Maybe it's not so much that the increment operation itself is faster, it's that adding the check allows the compiler to make an assumption that helps it inline or something?  Hard to say without seeing the asm for the hot loop (not just the non-inlined version of the function itself that @P.Hinker compiled).

Comment: Also note that if you don't need accesses to be a full memory barriers, you can get faster code on x86 (no MFENCE) by using `count_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)`, or maybe `std::memory_order_acquire` (which x86 does for free) in the accessor function some, and faster code for some (non-x86) architectures by using `count_.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)`  (or `MO_relaxed`).  Choose your memory ordering semantics so they don't generate a slow StoreLoad barrier if you don't need one.  atomic read-modify-write insns on x86 (using the LOCK prefix) are already full barriers, though.

Comment: @user2296177: ok, i7-930 is a 2nd-gen Nehalem (Westmere) CPU.  Tight loops should fit in the 28uop (~28 insn) loop buffer.  So tricky stuff like instruction alignment probably isn't what's slowing down the slower version.  Maybe if you looked at some performance counters, you could figure out if there was one spot where execution was stalling?

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried those memory orderings and they gave no performance gain. Of course, that is obviously because x86-64 must not benefit that much from it. This was just during a testing phase where I keep all memory orderings as sequentially consistent.

Comment: @user2296177: Like I said, the operator++ will only be faster on non-x86 (e.g. ARM, PowerPC). x86 atomic increment has to use `lock`ed instructions, which is already a full memory barrier (same as MFENCE).  Some other architectures can do an atomic RMW without also synchronizing all other memory operations, so the default `MO_seq_cst` has to use an expensive barrier.  Where you **will see a gain on x86** (including x86-64) is **in the accessor function**:  `size_type count() const`.  On x86, the compiler can just use a simple load unless you use the default `MO_seq_cst`, which requires MFENCE.

Comment: **Unable to reproduce**. You'd better link to reliable testing, and provide the assembly generated for the testing loop in each case.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce this.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I've added the assembly code.

Answer (score 2):

Fun with [ordering of tests](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac1d67a3459b8090).

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out

Average 1: 159 ms

Average 2: 165 ms
```

Here the "Average 2" test is run first.

Apparently it sort of primes the pump (preparing things) for the following test of "Average 1".

Comment: I understand that, and my question's code was a bit misleading, because the actual results (the ones that give me the big difference) don't have the priming that could cause better timings to occur for #2.

Comment: @user2296177: Using your latest test I'm unable to reproduce. On the contrary, with both MinGW g++ 5.1.0 and Visual C++ 2015 the simple `operator++` runs in about 170 ms, and the checked `operator++` in 335 ms. For g++ I used the [libatomic implementation from gcc pages](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=libatomic.c). This is an old laptop running Windows 7. If you're curious about the long execution times. :)

Comment: That's strange. I'm using the default VC++ implementation. No matter what I do, version 2 is always faster under full optimization release mode, but slower in debug mode. Thanks for doing tests on your system! It's just difficult to properly decide on which one to use when I get such results. I suppose the interface could provide a checked and an unchecked version.

Comment: Hm, I just used `/O2` with MSVC, but I now tried with `/Ox`. Same result. http://pastie.org/10489923

Comment: I downvoted because order of testing (cache effects, etc.) isn't a sufficient explanation for several milliseconds of difference.  The early versions of the question only had full test code in an external link, but now that it's clarified, it's definitely not the right answer.  Also, re: your comment from 2 hours ago where you found the checked version took about 2x as long, did you make the same mistake I did at first, and just uncomment the `2.` lines, without commenting the `1.` line?  That gets two atomic memory increments into the loop.

Comment: @PeterCordes: "isn't a sufficient explanation for several milliseconds of difference", well that's arguing with facts. The facts are that it explained a several milliseconds difference, about 10. Re the comment about 2x difference, yes I did make that mistake, sorry. Thanks. When I corrected and retested there's no significant difference, so, unable to reproduce. Voted to close the question because it's not reproducible.

Comment: I'm using the exact same code for testing that you are, assuming you kept everything and just commented out the count lines. Changing the loop count to something higher gives me 250ms avg for 1. and 205 ms avg for 2. I hope the assembly code can help.

Comment: @user2296177: Running the code [on Coliro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a8dd0bad6796f37) gives much variation, but not more than one can still say that there are no significant differences. Anyway that's the code used, after correcting the silly error noted by Peter Cordes. Local compilers g++ 5.1.0 and Visual C++ 2015.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the two member functions get inlined but the generated code is significantly different :

```
.L5:
        movq    $-1, %rdx
        lock xaddq      %rdx, (%rsp)
        testq   %rdx, %rdx
        je      .L14
        subq    $1, %rax
        jne     .L5
```

vs

```
.L3:
        lock addq       $1, (%rsp)
        subq    $1, %rax
        jne     .L3
```

I'm using g++ 5.1.1 on fedora, you'll want to generate the assembly (with the -S compiler flag) and look to see what your compiler is doing.  It's hard to imagine the first version running significantly faster.

Comment: This looks like you compare assembly for `operator--` to assembly for `operator++`, but the test & problem concerns `operator++` exclusively, namely with and without the `if` and throwing.

Comment: With gcc 4.9.2, `g++ -std=gnu++1y -O3 -march=native` on my Sandybridge desktop: They both compile to near-identical loops that run at the same speed. There's a `je exception_handler` after the `lock add $1, (%rsp)` in the version with checking, but the loop is still bottlenecked by `lock add` throughput. IDK what MSVC is doing, but clearly it's doing something different from gcc, because you're right there's that gcc's v2 can't be faster.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should have no trouble detecting that the if condition will never be satisfied in your test program. Consequently, what you're timing is some combination of randomness in optimization and other odd effects; e.g. maybe the very first loop iteration triggers a page fault as you haven't accessed the memory yet.

Comment: gcc 4.9.2 still checks it every iteration, even in the inlined version in `main`.  I guess compilers aren't good at deciding that nobody else can possibly have a reference to an atomic variable, and optimize away the checks.  Although, gcc does check the loop condition based on a register, rather than the result of the add.  So it takes advantage of the fact that the atomic is a local variable for that optimization.  Also, your page fault theory doesn't make any sense when you look at how all the iterations are the same number of ms, with a few outliers at startup for both.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You're failing to note the time of posting of answer, and time of edits of question. The question has changed since this answer. And right now it's non-reproducible for me.

Answer (score 0):

gcc makes different code than MSVC.  The v1 and v2 codes are extremely similar.  See the loop involving the `lock add` [in the asm on godbolt](http://goo.gl/HZsO2m).  They run at identical speed (on my Sandybridge CPU), bottlenecked on `lock add` throughput only (one per 19 cycles, with plenty of execution resources left over to handle the other instructions.  See http://agner.org/optimize for insn latency/throughput tables, and some nice guides.)  According to `ocperf.py`, gcc's v2 runs at 0.17 instructions per cycle, 0.61 uops per cycle (fused-domain).

MSVC does some strange things for v2, but I still can't explain why there'd be a bottleneck other than the `lock xadd` throughput, because locked instructions are very slow.  The only difference that I think might matter is that v2 uses a register address for the `lock xadd`, instead of an absolute address.

```
lock xadd   qword ptr [ac],rcx    ; v1: ac is a 32bit absolute address

lock xadd   qword ptr [rax],r8    ; v2: rax is a pointer (reloaded from memory every time through the loop)
```

Agner Fog's microarch docs don't go into much detail about how `lock`ed instructions affect the execution of surrounding instructions, e.g. whether they tie up execution ports for longer than you'd expect based on how many uops they decode to.  His instruction tables don't even have uop counts for them before Sandybridge (maybe because SnB introduced the uop cache, which makes the number of uops matter more.)

MSVC's v2 leaves the pointer to the atomic variable, and the loop upper-bound (`n`) in memory, and loads them every iteration.  This shouldn't be a problem, though.  They will stay hot in L1 cache, and the extra two load uops every iteration shouldn't be a factor.  I don't have a Nehalem to test with, so it's probably not worth wrapping some register-init code around that loop to try it on my SandyBridge (I don't have MSVC, or even a Windows computer to test with).  I have seen cases where extra memory operations actually sped up some code by a small amount, but that seems weird for this case.

Not that uop throughput should be anywhere near a factor, but according to IACA the bottom of the loop still micro and macro fuses down to one compare-and-branch with a memory operand, on Nehalem.

```
cmp   r9,qword [rbx]   ; loop upper-bound in memory
jb    loopv2
```

IACA says the v2 loop is a total of 12 uops on Nehalem.  I don't think it properly accounts for the limited throughput of locked instructions, though, since it thinks the loop will run at one iteration per 3.2 clocks.  It says v1 is 8 uops and should run at one iteration per 3.0 clocks.  So IACA doesn't model the CPU behaviour in enough detail to say anything useful for this case.  Both loops should be running from the 28uop loop buffer on Nehalem, not that the frontend is anywhere near being a bottleneck at well under one instructions per cycle!

---

My previous guess about the code having an extra MFENCE was based on misreading the source, thinking the loop counter was atomic, and not just an integer of the `size_type` of the atomic.  Which doesn't make sense, BTW:

The loop counter should be sized based on the iteration count, not whatever random type you're testing `atomic_counter` with.  If it's a slow floating-point or extended precision type or something, you don't want to pay a penalty in loop overhead as well.  And testing an 8-bit atomic counter would make an infinite loop.  Anyway, not the issue here.  The code as written is fine for simple integer types.

Comment: The loop counter is not atomic, it is `atomic_counter<>::size_type` which is `std::size_t` when the template argument is not specified. I'll get the assembly ASAP. I tested it out with `int` anyway, and it gives me the same result.

Comment: @user2296177: oh right, of course.  I see now >.<.  Can you still reproduce the speed diff?  The asm for the 2nd version still has a `lock xadd` in the loop, and some other memory ops.  I'll have another look after supper and update my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's still reproducible with the code in the question. The only thing that kind of caught my eye was that the 2nd version was purely register based, but I might be wrong, since I'm not that familiar with ASM.

Comment: @user2296177: square brackets around something in asm dereferences it.  So `[rax]` as a source or destination operand is the memory location pointed to by the value of the rax register.  (LEA is an exception to the rule: it loads the address, rather than the value.  After the XADD, `lea rax, `[r8+1]` does rax = r8+1, not a load from memory.  It's doing that because xadd leaves the *old* value in the source register, but your code compares against the new value.  (It's crappy asm anyway, it could just conditional-branch on the carry flag as set by XADD (or the zero flag). instead of lea/test)

Comment: @user2296177: I don't see anything in the V2 asm that explains how it could possibly be faster, unless somehow absolute addressing modes are slower with locked instructions on Nehalem.  Or there's some other subtle bottleneck that stops the very simple V1 code from doing `lock xadd` instructions back-to-back at max throughput.

Comment: @user2296177: I give up, I can't figure out why a Nehalem CPU would run that code more slowly.  I don't have one to test on, so I can't check perf counters myself.  Even if I did, I'm not sure what I'd look for.  v2 definitely takes more instructions, so inlining it all over the place will increase your code size by more than inlining v1.  The cost of a single atomic operation occasionally is not necessarily exactly the same as the throughput of doing it back-to-back.  Out-of-order execution CPUs can do multiple things at once.  **microbenchmarks aren't always useful**.

Comment: You're sure this isn't a testing-order problem?  Like CPU-clock ramp-up?

Comment: Yeah, I'm fairly sure, since I can execute the tests in any order and I always get better results for v2; it must be a really weird edge case.

Comment: @user2296177: yup, and probably only something that happens in a tight loop.  Since MSVC seems to suck at generating `lock add [rax], 1 / jz exception` the way gcc does, try writing your code to test the previous value.  (i.e. use post-increment and test against `max` in operator++).  You're looking for the asm to be shorter, something like `lock xadd [rax], r8 / cmp r8, -1 / je exception`.  It's a mystery to me why MSVC doesn't pull the `mov r8d, 1` out of the loop, but in most cases you won't have this operator in a *tight* loop anyway, so regs probably get re-used for other stuff anyway.